# I want to track user's real world activity on android ,which method is better ,GPS or activityRecognition?

Tags: android

I want to track user's real world activity on android  ,which method is better ,GPS or activityRecognition?
and one of the situation is when user suddenly running, i want to detect user's activity change immediately how can i do?

Comment: ActivityRecognition is better.  Using GPS, you'll have to do all the work Google does for you with activity recognition.  As for immediately-  probably not possible.  It takes a little bit of time/data to figure out what's happening-  is the user running?  Got on a bike or car?  Or was it just a sensor blip?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your basic requirements I'll suggest you to use ActivityRecogniserAPI, but ActivityRecogniserAPI doesn't give you the results immediately specially on the places where Location Services are not responding quickly.
But if you use GPS then you can speedup the process little bit, but you have to do a-lot or work to achieve this by running some process, doing calculations, handling events etc. It will be little bit fast as compared to ActivityRecogniserAPI but you will be having issue in this as well when Location Services are not responding quickly.

**If the slow process works for you then I'll suggest you to use ActivityRecogniserAPI.**